# rspec - command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

As part of assignment I am creating a basic website. **When rails server is not running and I execute "rspec" for root directory, the rspec is executed**. However tests fail. When I start rails server and execute rspec from another terminal window (after going to root directory), rspec doesnt work. I get the following message -

> Tushars-MacBook-Pro:recipefinder tusharsaurabh$ rspec
>   -bash: rspec: command not found

Please let me know, how to fix it.

Answer (score 34):

Maybe your `rspec` command isn't installed system-wide, that's ok, try running

```
bundle exec rspec
```

It should work.

Comment: This fixed my issue immediately. Is it possible to explain what was causing it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could be great if you add the solution, too.

Comment: you might need to just run ```bundle```

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem using: `gem install rspec`. There are others solutions that I didn't try like: `sudo gem install rspec`, another one `bundle exec rspec spec`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run the rails server to execute the rspec. Rspec runs standalone. just run the `rspec spec`. It will run the specs you have written in the spec folder of your project.

If you need both to be running then you need to do something like this.It might work. Please try it.

add to your gem file:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

hit bundle from your console.

```
bundle
rails generate rspec:install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same challenge when working on a Rails 6 application:

After adding `rspec` to my `Gemfile` using:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0'
end
```

And installing it using `bundle install` when I run the command `rspec` I get the error:

> rspec command not found

**Here's how I fixed it**:

**Solution 1**

Since `rspec` is not globally installed on your system, but in your project, you will need to run the command each time:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

**Solution 2**

Instead of the verbose `bundle exec rspec` we could generate binstubs for rspec so can that we run our specs with `bin/rspec` or just `rspec` using the command:

```
bundle binstubs rspec-core
```

**Note**: Close your current terminal/shell and reopen a new one after running the command.

Now you can run the command `rspec` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of rails 7 use

```
**bin/bundle exec rspec spec**
```